# If else conditional based on script type

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm working on a small snippet to determine when to inject HTML and I am having a hard time properly targeting the proper conditional.

So below, I will go into detail what I'm attempting to do:

I have the following `<script>` embed in the footer with an ID which changes the 'text/plain' to 'text/javascript' based on a plugin:

```
<script type="text/plain" id="google-maps-api-script" class="optanon-category-C0004" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?php echo get_field('google_maps_api_key', 'option') ?>&v=weekly"></script>
```

Inside the js, I am console logging the element ID using:

```
const script = $('#google-maps-api-script');
console.log(script);
```

This gives me a S.fn.init return with the [0] index always:
[image]

Now inside the attributes, I want to be able to do an If/else conditional based on the script type. So the attributes -> [0] or type -> nodeValue/value reveal that:
[image]

How can I properly make a conditional that says:

```
If (#google-maps-api-script type is 'text/plain') {
   // Do something
} else or if it's 'text/javascript')) {
   // Do something else
}
```

All help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.attr('type')` to get it:

```
if ($("#google-maps-api-script").attr("type") == "text/plain")) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```